# How can I allow user to continue scrolling after assigning a position: fixed value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sorry the question is vague, but if you look at my code it should be clearer.

```js
    var phadesTriggered = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.frame').css({height: new windowDimensions().height + 'px'});
      $('.container').css({height: new windowDimensions().height + 1 + 'px'});
      $('.spacer').css({height: new windowDimensions().height + 1 + 'px'});
      $('.phade').css({height: new windowDimensions().height});
    });
    function documentDimensions () {
      this.height = $(document).height();
      this.width = $(document).width();
    }
    function windowDimensions () {
      this.height = $(window).height();
      this.width = $(window).width();
    }
    function getScroll () {
      return $('#page').scrollTop();
    }
    $('#page').scroll(function () {
      var scroll = Math.floor(getScroll() / new windowDimensions().height) * new windowDimensions().height;
      var currentPhade = document.getElementsByClassName('phade')[scroll / new windowDimensions().height];
      if ($(currentPhade).css('display') === 'none') {
        $(currentPhade).css('display', 'block');
        $('#page').scrollTop(scroll, 0);
        $(currentPhade).animate({opacity: '1'}, 3000);
        $(currentPhade).addClass('fixed');
        phadesTriggered++;
        
        if (phadesTriggered >= document.getElementsByClassName('phade').length) {
          $('.spacer').css('display', 'none');
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sphinx Scroller</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-blue-grey.css"/>
  <style>
    .show {
      display: block;
    } .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    .frame {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    }
    
    .phade {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .spacer { /* This space has been left intentionally blank */ }
    
    .halo {
      background-image: url('https://content.halocdn.com/media/Default/games/halo-5-guardians/page/h5-guardians-facebook-1200x630-ba103624b3f34af79fe8cb2d340dce3f.jpg');
    }
    
    .roblox {
      background-image: url('https://images.rbxcdn.com/d66ae37d46e00a1ecacfe9531986690a.jpg');
    }
    
    .fixed {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="frame" id="page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="phade halo">ww</div>
      <div class="phade roblox">ww</div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will notice that a Halo image fades in when the user scrolls. Ideally, you would want to continue scrolling for a Roblox image (sorry for the image choices, I just needed to pick quick images).

So, my question is, how can I make sure the user can continue on the the second 'phade'?

Comment: Why would you call so, many `new` instances? The entire point would be to store the instance into a variable so you would have property access, so one call gets the `.height` and `.width`. I think your problem is `$('#page').scrollTop(scroll, 0);`, though. Scrolling for what? No content.

Comment: I eliminated the scrollTop, it didn't work. Also, the `new` instances were a blunder... I didn't realize the mistake until I had used it about 5 times.